# How to convvert Indian language .tex file to epub with a neat output

Tags: fonts, equations, tex4ht, epub

I am trying to convert a book in Malayalam prepared using XeLaTeX into an epub file. I tried with Calibre, which gave a file that had many problems with the Malayalam text. Then I tried with pandoc, which gave a largely neat output, but with a few problems with characters and some equations shown as tex command itself. Another problem I found was that the short caption option that I had used in figures were seen as errors when compiling with pandoc. I then had to remove them from the figure environment.

And I don't want a pdf file that fits my tab or phone, as pdf behaves differently from epub. So, changing the size or page dimensions is not a solution at all. That is not what I am looking for at all.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: this is hard without some example of your input. did you try [tex4ebook](ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/support/tex4ebook/tex4ebook-doc.pdf)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't provide any test file, so I will just use some sample I've found on the Internet:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Rachana}[Script=Malayalam]
\newfontfamily\malayalamfont{Rachana}[Script=Malayalam]
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{malayalam}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\title{സ്വർണം}
\author{മലയാളം വിക്കിപീഡിയ}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\section{സ്വർണം}

മൃദുവും തിളക്കമുള്ളതുമായ മഞ്ഞലോഹമാണ് സ്വർണം. വിലയേറിയ ലോഹമായ സ്വർണം, നാണയമായും, ആഭരണങ്ങളുടെ രൂപത്തിലും നൂറ്റാണ്ടുകളായി മനുഷ്യൻ ഉപയോഗിച്ചു പോരുന്നു. 
ചെറിയ കഷണങ്ങളും തരികളുമായി സ്വതന്ത്രാവസ്ഥയിൽത്തന്നെ പ്രകൃതിയിൽ ഈ ലോഹം കണ്ടുവരുന്നു. ലോഹങ്ങളിൽ വച്ച് ഏറ്റവും നന്നായി രൂപഭേദം വരുത്താവുന്ന ലോഹമാണിത്.
\footnote{http://www.webelements.com/webelements/elements/text/Au/key.html "Key properties of gold" (in ഇംഗ്ലീഷ്). ശേഖരിച്ചത് 2007-06-18.}

\section{ഗുണങ്ങൾ}
സ്വർണത്തിന്റെ അണുസംഖ്യ 79-ഉം പ്രതീകം Au എന്നുമാണ്. ഔറം എന്ന ലത്തീൻ വാക്കിൽ നിന്നാണ് Au എന്ന പ്രതീകം ഉണ്ടായത്.
ഏറ്റവും നന്നായി രൂപഭേദം വരുത്താൻ സാധിക്കുന്ന ലോഹമാണ് സ്വർണ്ണം. ഒരു ഗ്രാം സ്വർണ്ണം അടിച്ചു പരത്തി ഒരു ചതുരശ്രമീറ്റർ വിസ്തീർണ്ണമുള്ള ഒരു തകിടാക്കി മാറ്റാൻ സാധിക്കും. 
അതായത് 0.000013 സെന്റീമീറ്റർ വരെ ഇതിന്റെ കനം കുറക്കാൻ കഴിയും. അതു പോലെ വെറും 29 ഗ്രാം സ്വർണ്ണം ഉപയോഗിച്ച് 100 കിലോ മീറ്റർ നീളമുള്ള കമ്പിയുണ്ടാക്കാനും സാധിക്കും. 

\section{ചരിത്രം}
ചരിത്രാതീത കാലം മുതൽക്കേ അറിയപ്പെട്ടിരുന്ന അമൂല്യലോഹമാണ്‌ സ്വർണ്ണം. ഒരുപക്ഷേ മനുഷ്യൻ ആദ്യമായി ഉപയോഗിച്ച ലോഹവും ഇതുതന്നെയായിരിക്കണം.
ബി.സി.ഇ. 2600 ലെ ഈജിപ്ഷ്യൻ ഹീറോഗ്ലിഫിക്സ് ലിഖിതങ്ങളിൽ ഈജിപ്തിൽ സ്വർണ്ണം സുലഭമായിരുന്നെന്ന് പരാമർശിക്കുന്നുണ്ട്.
ചരിത്രം പരിശോധിച്ചാൽ ഈജിപ്തും നുബിയയുമാണ്‌ ലോകത്തിൽ ഏറ്റവുമധികം സ്വർണ്ണം ഉല്പ്പാദിപ്പിച്ചിരുന്ന മേഖലകൾ. ബൈബിളിലെ പഴയ നിയമത്തിൽ സ്വർണ്ണത്തെപ്പറ്റി പലവട്ടം പരാമർശിക്കുന്നുണ്ട്.



ദുവും തിളക്കമുള്ളതുമായ മഞ്ഞലോഹമാണ് സ്വർണം. വിലയേറിയ ലോഹമായ സ്വർണം, നാണയമായും, ആഭരണങ്ങളുടെ രൂപത്തിലും നൂറ്റാണ്ടുകളായി മനുഷ്യൻ ഉപയോഗിച്ചു പോരുന്നു. 
ചെറിയ കഷണങ്ങളും തരികളുമായി സ്വതന്ത്രാവസ്ഥയിൽത്തന്നെ പ്രകൃതിയിൽ ഈ ലോഹം കണ്ടുവരുന്നു. ലോഹങ്ങളിൽ വച്ച് ഏറ്റവും നന്നായി രൂപഭേദം വരുത്താവുന്ന ലോഹമാണിത്.



\begin{equation} \label{eq1}
  \begin{split}
    A & = \frac{\pi r^2}{2} \\
     & = \frac{1}{2} \pi r^2
  \end{split}
\end{equation}


\end{document}
```

It is just some basic document that uses `Fontspec` and `Polyglossia`. You can compile it using

```
tex4ebook -l filename.tex
```

This command will produce Epub 2 file, using LuaLaTeX for compilation. The version of `tex4ebook` included in TeX Live doesn't support `XeTeX`, so we need to use LuaTeX instead.

There are some problems with this file, most notably wrong titlepage:

[image]

We also may want to use a cover image and some custom CSS file. For this, configuration file is needed. Save the following code as `myconfig.cfg`:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\def\blockelement#1{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{#1}}
\Configure{thanks author date and}
{\blockelement{<div class="thanks">}}
{\blockelement{</div>}}
{\blockelement{<div class="author">}\NoFonts}
{\EndNoFonts\blockelement{</div>}}
{\blockelement{<div class="date">}\NoFonts}
{\EndNoFonts\blockelement{</div>}}
{\blockelement{<br class="and" />}}
{\blockelement{<br />}}

\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css" />}}
\special{t4ht+@File: mystyle.css}

\CoverMetadata{mycover.png}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

The `\Configure{thanks author date and}` take care of the wrong title page. `\CoverMetadata{mycover.png}` add a cover image and `\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css" />}}` includes the custom CSS file. `\special{t4ht+@File: mystyle.css}` is needed to include it in the Epub file.

You can compile your document with the config file using

```
 tex4ebook -lc myconfig.cfg filename.tex
```

Another issue is math. Epub 2 isn't really good format of scientific documents, math can be included only as bitmap picture. It may not look really great.

It is better to use more modern version Epub 3. It supports MathMl, which should look better than bitmap images. The problem is that MathMl isn't really well supported by the Epub reading systems. Anyway, you can try it:

```
 tex4ebook -lc myconfig.cfg -f epub3 filename.tex mathml
```

If MathMl doesn't work for you, it is possible to use SVG images, which should look better than bitmaps:

```
 tex4ebook -lc myconfig.cfg -f epub3 filename.tex svg
```

This is the result in Calibre:

[image]
[image]

Comment: First of all, so sorry for the long delay in responding. I was quite busy with some other work and I actually entrusted this job with a friend. But, thank you so much for your answer.